# Using Railo 3.2 WAR with Tomcat vhosts

Tags: tomcat7, railo

I've deployed the `railo-3.2.3.000.war` and I get the welcome page at `http://localhost:8080/railo-3.2.3.000/` which is great but what now? How do I make my CFML-based vhosts actually recognise and use it? In particular, can it be done so all my existing 50+ vhosts share that one deployment and in a way that I can automate new vhosts (like through the manager script interface)?

Do I need to manually edit `catalina.properties` to load JAR's from `/var/lib/tomcat-7/webapps/railo-3.2.3.000/WEB-INF/lib/`? Or is there another way?

I'm really trying to avoid modifying Tomcat core files because I want a solution that's easy to roll out to other servers and upgrade in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not want to use a WAR deployment for multiple virtual hosts. You would generally use a WAR deployment for each virtual host. You want a "global install" or "common classpath" style installation. In a nutshell, this involves dropping Railo JARs in a common Tomcat classpath and adding various servlet (and other) config info from a Railo WAR's web.xml to Tomcat's global web.xml file. There are plenty of guides and blog posts out there if you'd like to handle this manually, but if you don't have a reason to do otherwise, I'd recommend looking at the Vivio Technologies installers:

http://www.viviotech.net/company/installers.cfm

Here's some documentation for the Vivio Railo installer:

http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/Installation:InstallerDocumentation

And here's some more installation guides type stuff (potentially a few dated references under there):

http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/Railo_Installation

Once you have a global installation set, adding additional virtual hosts is a simple matter of modifying Tomcat's server.xml file with new Host entries. You should find details and examples of this in the above Vivio Railo Installer documentation. You may also be able to use Tomcat Admin Web apps to do the same, but I've always edited server.xml myself, and skipped installing Tomcat Admin apps altogether. HTH!